# Webpack production build bundle is too huge

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using React with Webpack for my project. My project is very very huge. It consists of 10-12 modules and bundling of one module related JS files is taking 460KB file size. I am worried that it may take up to 5MB bundle size after I wrote code for all the modules in my project.
How can I reduce the bundle size or any suggestions to bundle for large scalable project with React and Webpack.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use tree shaking of your project after you finish it.
Take a look at the official webpack docs for this: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: Thanks for your response. However I am not using much of external libraries. My project internal code is too huge and make the bundle size huge. How webpack tree shaking would help me for my huge internal project code bundling?

Answer (score 0):

Things you can do to keep the bundle size at minimum.

- Code splitting
- Production configuration optimization e.g `webpack --mode production`
- gZip compression
- minify (uglify) code

This will reduce your bundle size drastically.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am already using production mode and i think production mode always minify your code, no need to minify(uglify) code separately for production mode. in production mode build my bundle size is too huge. probably i need to further minimize or look for other alternative for huge bundle size.

Comment: Okay, then go for compression. And code splitting. This will resolve all of your problems.